# VB.NET : Change SQL Server Authentication mode

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, windows

We are using the following code to change the SQL Server authentication from Windows mode to mixed mode.

```
query.CommandText = "EXEC xp_instance_regwrite 'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE', 'Software\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQLSERVER', 'LoginMode', REG_DWORD, 2"
query.CommandType = CommandType.Text
query.ExecuteScalar()
```

During the execution we get the following error.

> RegCreateKeyEx() returned error 5, 'Access is denied.'

We could change the authentication mode manually. However we need to do this work programmatically.

Help needed.

Comment: Take a look at the permissions needed to change the registry key and run the program under an account that has the proper authentication to make the change.

Comment: Well if the program is run  as an administrator it may work?

Comment: It might - easiest way to find out is to do it and see what happens.

Comment: Same error running even if the application is run as an administrator.

Comment: From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa289494%28v=vs.71%29.aspx): "Visual Basic .NET offers four functions to access the registry. To use them, you must have Read and Write permission from the RegistryPermissionAccess enumeration. Any code running with full trust (under the default security policy, this is any code installed on the user's local hard drive) has the necessary permissions to access the registry. For more information, see RegistryPermission Class."  Do note that this is an older article (VS.NET 2003), but the principles are most likely the same.

Comment: If you're already doing this in VB.NET - why not just use the .NET [`Registry`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.registry%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class to do this? Why bother executing a T-SQL statement which then writes into the registry? Seems unnecessarily complicated....$

Comment: @marc_s tried that now. Executing but no changes made. I will post it in a new thread now.

Answer (score 1):

Do this with SMO. I'm going to write it in powershell, but it should be immediately transferable to VB.NET

```
import-module sqlps -disablenamechecking;

$s = new-object microsoft.sqlserver.management.smo.server '.';
$s.LoginMode = 'mixed';
$s.alter();
```

This has the advantage of being durable to changes to the location of the registry key across versions (assuming that MS keeps the SMO interface up to date, which they in all likelihood will) and will work with named instances (you'd have to change the registry location in your solution for yours to work).